# python dataframe: return column name in apply lambda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, lambda

I want to use ***apply(applymap) and lambda*** functions to get the column name for every element in ***dfx*** (a dataframe). The ***lambda*** function is used for mapping another dataframe into ***dfx***, and it will be rewritten afterwards.

**dfx**

```
             A     B    C
2011-01-10   123   12   123 
2011-01-10   12    32   312
2011-01-11   44    1    30.99
```

**pseudocode**

```
output = dfx.apply(lambda r:r.column)
```

I don't know how to write this part "r:r.column"

**intended output**

```
             A    B    C
2011-01-10   A    B    C 
2011-01-10   A    B    C
2011-01-11   A    B    C
```

Any help is more than welcome! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: When you say that the function will be rewritten afterwards, do you mean that you need access to the column's values as well, or do you just need the column names?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign via [`pd.DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df.iloc[:] = df.columns

print(df)

            A  B  C
2011-01-10  A  B  C
2011-01-10  A  B  C
2011-01-11  A  B  C
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `apply` a function that function takes as an argument a `Series` corresponding to a row. You can change this to a column by passing the kwarg `axis=1` to `apply`. A `Series` does not have columns (axis 1) - only an index (axis 0). Instead you can use the original DataFrame:

```
dfx.apply(lambda s: dfx.columns, axis=1)
```

returns

```
            A  B  C
2011-01-10  A  B  C
2011-01-10  A  B  C
2011-01-11  A  B  C
```

**Note**: There are certainly better ways of doing this that don't "use apply and lambda functions" as desired.

Comment: this doesn't work as reported I get `Index([ 'A', 'B', ..])` at every row